# Get the version and OS type of the host

Tags: scripting

I am trying to get the release version of Red Hat and SUSE servers based on input from admin server which has passwdless authentication to all servers. I am neither getting error nor output, below is the code

```
version()
{
SERVERS='/HOME/servers' 
read -p $'Enter the server name:\n' server_name
EXIST=`cat $SERVERS|grep -i $server_name|wc -l`
if [ $EXIST -gt 0 ];then
RELEASE1='ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" "$server_name" cat /etc/issue'
COUNT1=`ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" "$server_name" cat /etc/issue|wc -l`
VERSION1=`ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" "$server_name" cat /etc/issue|awk '/Red/ && /Hat/'`
COUNT2=`ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" "$server_name" cat /etc/issue|awk '/Red/ && /Hat/'|wc -l`

if [[ -f $RELEASE1 && -s $RELEASE1 ]];then
    if [ $COUNT1 -gt 0 ];then
        echo -e " $RELEASE1 "
    elif [ $COUNT2 -gt 0 ];then
        echo -e " $VERSION1 "

    else
        echo "                  "
 fi
```

else
        echo "                  "

fi

Comment: I can see that the text highlighting is going wrong. Therefore you have miss-matching quotes. Please fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two backticks on line-10.  For syntax checking you can always use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

It is far preferred (readable too) to use `$(...)` for command substitution in lieu of the archaic back-quote form.

As an aside, rather than parsing `/etc/issue` and or files like `/etc/redhat-release`, install `lsb_release` to obtain release and distribution information.

Comment: Or **ANY** good editor

Comment: Lines 7 & 8 are presumably intended to be command substitutions as well?

Comment: @steeldriver : so it would/should be.  I focused on syntax only :-(